# Android Parcelable: How to read / write string array lists and integer arrays

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am having problems trying to write String array lists and integer arrays to parcel.

this is my class fields

```
String uniqueDate;
ArrayList <String> set1Numbers;
ArrayList <String> set2Numbers;
ArrayList <String> UIDs;
int[] selectedStatus;
```

This part writes the data to parcel

```
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) 
    {
        dest.writeString(uniqueDate);
        dest.writeStringList(set1Numbers);
        dest.writeStringList(set2Numbers);
        dest.writeStringList(UIDs);
        dest.writeIntArray(selectedStatus);
    }
```

This part reads it. I think the problem is here

```
PNItems(Parcel in)
    {
        this.uniqueDate = in.readString();
        in.readStringList(set1Numbers);
        in.readStringList(set2Numbers);
        in.readStringList(UIDs);
        in.readIntArray(selectedStatus);
    }
```

Can someone please tell me how to do it, I could not find a tutorial on the internet with my problem.

Comment: *Post your stack trace from the crash.*

Comment: post the whole class where you want to implement Parcelable.

Comment: Use this tool to generate a `Parcelable` class: parcelabler http://www.parcelabler.com/

Comment: Never mind, I found what the problem is. I used some log statements. I find the data is present and is OK. Problem is caused by Spinner getting called when initialised which overwrites the data that was saved sigh :(

Answer (score 9):

If you look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readStringList(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)) for Parcel, readStringList() shows:

> Read into the given List items String objects that were written with writeStringList(List) at the current dataPosition().
>
> Returns
>   A newly created ArrayList containing strings with the same data as those that were previously written.

It requires that the List<> that you pass in is non-null (as it will populate it). Since this is your constructor, I would expect that your parameters are null, and that is why you crash. You should instead use [`Parcel#createStringArrayList()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#createStringArrayList()) to return a new List:

> Read and return a new ArrayList containing String objects from the parcel that was written with writeStringList(List) at the current dataPosition(). Returns null if the previously written list object was null.
>
> Returns
>   A newly created ArrayList containing strings with the same data as those that were previously written.

For example:

```
set1Numbers = in.createStringArrayList();
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any crashes. My spinner was overwriting the data because it gets called when it initialises.

Comment: `createStringArrayList()` was my rescue! Thanks!